# How to replace html element in simple_format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I define text = "abc".

Then, in html, `<%= simple_format(text) %>` produces `<p>"abc"</p>` and describes abc. I want to make this `<p class = 'some_class'>abc</p>`. How do I this?

I tried `<%= simple_format(text) %>.gsub(/<p>/, "<p class='some_class'>") %>`, but this produces `"<p class='some_class'>abc</p>"`, not `<p class='some_class'>"abc"</p>`.

If I can make `<p class='some_class'>abc</p>` from abc anyway, it isn't necessary to use simple_format. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple_format options.

```
simple_format(text, class: 'some_class')
```

and simple_format gives many convenience, Read document. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to use simple_format.

```
<p class="your class"><%= text %></p>
```

But you can provide a class to it:

```
<%= simple_format text, class: 'my_class' %>
```